# What can cause component to fire update cycle and render( ), but not to change DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a HOC, which manipulates the components by iterating through all their children and adding properties to them.

The manipulated components initially render properly. However, when there is a change, the changes don't reflect in DOM.

I have checked by logging that render and componentDidUpdate is fired, with correct values. If I don't wrap the component to HOC, everything works as expected.

This is the test component I use:

```
class ColorBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            value: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
        }
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.trace()
    }
    randomizeColor() {
        const colArr = []
        for(let i=0; i<3; i++) {
            const col = Math.round(Math.random() * 255)
            colArr.push(col)
        }
        this.setState({
            value: `rgb(${colArr})`
        })
    }

    render() {
        const style = {
            width: '20px',
            height: '20px',
            backgroundColor: this.state.value
        }
        console.log(style)
        return (
            <div>
                <br />
                <button onClick={ this.randomizeColor.bind(this) }>
                    Randomize
                </button>
                <div style={ style } />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

When logging the style, the color values are changing, but the DOM is not. The only difference compared to unwrapped component is that when I run console.trace() the trace stack is longer on wrapped component. I just don't know what to look from there.

```
componentDidUpdate  @   complex.js:118
componentDidUpdate  @   createPrototypeProxy.js:44
measureLifeCyclePerf    @   ReactCompositeComponent.js:75
(anonymous) @   ReactCompositeComponent.js:729
notifyAll   @   CallbackQueue.js:76
close   @   ReactReconcileTransaction.js:80
closeAll    @   Transaction.js:206
perform @   Transaction.js:153
perform @   Transaction.js:140
perform @   ReactUpdates.js:89
flushBatchedUpdates @   ReactUpdates.js:172
closeAll    @   Transaction.js:206
perform @   Transaction.js:153
batchedUpdates  @   ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
enqueueUpdate   @   ReactUpdates.js:200
enqueueUpdate   @   ReactUpdateQueue.js:24
enqueueSetState @   ReactUpdateQueue.js:219
./node_modules/react/lib/ReactBaseClasses.js.ReactComponent.setState    @   ReactBaseClasses.js:64
randomizeColor  @   complex.js:126
randomizeColor  @   createPrototypeProxy.js:44
./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactErrorUtils.js.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback   @   ReactErrorUtils.js:69
executeDispatch @   EventPluginUtils.js:85
executeDispatchesInOrder    @   EventPluginUtils.js:108
executeDispatchesAndRelease @   EventPluginHub.js:43
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @   EventPluginHub.js:54
forEachAccumulated  @   forEachAccumulated.js:24
processEventQueue   @   EventPluginHub.js:257
runEventQueueInBatch    @   ReactEventEmitterMixin.js:17
handleTopLevel  @   ReactEventEmitterMixin.js:28
handleTopLevelImpl  @   ReactEventListener.js:72
perform @   Transaction.js:140
batchedUpdates  @   ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates  @   ReactUpdates.js:97
dispatchEvent
```

My question is: what can cause the render to be fired but not to update DOM? What things should I be looking at the trace stack?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine. See the snippet below.  The only thing I can think is that something is wrong not with the component iteself but with the method you are using to render the component.

```js
class ColorBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            value: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
        }
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.trace()
    }
    randomizeColor() {
        const colArr = []
        for(let i=0; i<3; i++) {
            const col = Math.round(Math.random() * 255)
            colArr.push(col)
        }
        this.setState({
            value: `rgb(${colArr})`
        })
    }

    render() {
        const style = {
            width: '20px',
            height: '20px',
            backgroundColor: this.state.value
        }
        console.log(style)
        return (
            <div>
                <br />
                <button onClick={ this.randomizeColor.bind(this) }>
                    Randomize
                </button>
                <div style={ style } />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ColorBox />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```